# Activates default_button from Gtk.TreeView on a GtkDialog (python/Gtk3)

Tags: python, gtk3

I have a Dialog Window with a TreeView and two Buttons (Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL and Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT). I can't find how to activates the ResponseType.ACCEPT button when I press Enter inside the Gtk.TreeView. I set cant_datault on desired button and set_default on GtkDialog but Gtk.TreeView doesn't have an activates default method.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way I could find would be to use the "row-activated" signal within the TreeView. This is activated whenever you press Enter, double-click an item or press the Spacebar.

So for example:

```
treeview.connect("row-activated", lambda a, b, c: dialog.response(Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT))
```

I've used lambda to create the anonymous function, but if you have anything else that needs to run at the same time, you can swap it for a proper function.

Just be aware that if you also change your default response in the future, you'll need to update this function as well.